# Recover the deleted files in amazon ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-11.04, file-recovery

How I would recover the recent deleted files from amazon ec2 ubuntu server.For example The all "tar" files are removed unfortunately in amazon ec2 + ubuntu 11.04 instance.

The removed files should be retrieved.

Could you suggest for this problem?

Comment: How did they get deleted? Did you delete them from within the instance? Do you have a snapshot from when the data was still there? Where was the data stored (EBS or instance storage)?

Comment: I have deleted within the instance "rm *.tar".in the Desktop location

Comment: try superuser.com or askubuntu.com

Comment: Duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/357566/recover-the-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-amazon-ec2

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to do it if you rm *ed them. What type of file system did you delete them off of?

I would look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linuxunix-recover-deleted-files.html

That only works for text files... There is a recover command but that is for ext2